# Image getting rotated while inserting in rich textarea field using attachament

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, attachment, richtextarea, fileupload

1. Facing this problem while uploading image using iPhone salesforce one app.
2. In the attachment the image is showing right, but when the same image from attachament is inserted into rich textarea it is being rotated 90deg anticlockwise.
3. For android it's working fine.
4. I am inserting this image in rich text area using image tag

Code snippet

5. I have already tried style in img tag but no luck.

Expected -
[image]

Actual -
[image]